# Error 5067 - How can I bypass it and implement Sorbet on my project?

Tags: sorbet

I use `rails-observers gem` and I just can't run `srb tc` without errors...

```
app/models/supplier_observer.rb:3: The super class ActiveRecord::Observer of SupplierObserver does not derive from Class https://srb.help/5067
     3 |class SupplierObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    sorbet/rbi/todo.rbi:20: ActiveRecord::Observer defined here
    20 |module ActiveRecord::Observer; end
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

app/models/supplier_observer.rb
`class SupplierObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer`

sorbet/rbi/todo.rbi
`module ActiveRecord::Observer; end`

`tapioca gem rails-observers` doesn't resolve the problem

I need a way to bypass it and implement Sorbet on my project

Comment: Hmmmm strange. The RBI should read `class ActiveModel::Observer < Object; end`

Answer (score 1):

Since the `todo.rbi` file is generated by Tapioca/Sorbet for any class/module that is used in the codebase but has not been declared, it includes all entries as `module`s (since it doesn't know if it should be a class or a module). In this case, that assumption ends up being incorrect.

The fix is to edit the `todo.rbi` file and change:

```rb
module ActiveRecord::Observer; end
```

on line 20 to:

```rb
class ActiveRecord::Observer; end
```

By the way, the better fix is to get Tapioca to generate an RBI file for `rails-observers`. You might be just missing a require in the `sorbet/tapioca/require.rb` file or something.